# About screen transition in persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I have specified 5 screens for the navigation bar.
The screen placed in the center is AddItemPage, and I want to hide the navigation bar on AddItemPage.
I was able to specify withNavBar: false in onItemSelected and transition to AddItemPage, but when I press the Android back key, AddItemPage with a navigation bar is displayed.

```
class MainNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  MainNavigationBar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: PersistentTabView(
          context,
          screens: _pages,
          items: [
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month_outlined),
              activeColorPrimary: Colors.pink,
              inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
            ),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.bar_chart),
              activeColorPrimary: Colors.pink,
              inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
            ),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add,),
              activeColorPrimary: Colors.pink,
              inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
            ),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
              activeColorPrimary: Colors.pink,
              inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
            ),
            PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.people),
              activeColorPrimary: Colors.pink,
              inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
          onItemSelected: (index) {
            if (index == 2) {
              pushNewScreen<dynamic>(
                context,
                screen: const AddItemPage(),
                withNavBar: false,
              );
            }
          },
        )
    );
  }

  final _pages = <Widget>[
    const CalendarPage(),
    const ChartPage(),
    const AddItemPage(),
    const SettingsPage(),
    const PeoplesPage(),
  ];
}
```

I would like to return to the originally displayed page (CalendarPage, ChartPage, etc.) when the Android back key is selected, but how should I implement this?